# Shareable gallery item image

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, twitter, share

I have a gallery which consists of various images. When an image is clicked it expands to show an enlarged version of the image and some text on the right. I have added social sharing buttons but I am having to luck retrieving the actual link to the image. Here is what i have so far.

```
<div class="grid__item" data-size="1280x857">
    <a href="candle.jpeg" class="img-wrap"><img src="candle.jpeg" alt="img06" /></a>
        <div class="description description--grid">
            <h3>Candle Light</h3>
            <div class="details">
                <ul>
                    <li><i class="icon icon-film"></i><span>Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban</span></li>

                </ul>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <ul class="share-buttons">
                        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=&t=" title="Share on Facebook" target="_blank" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + encodeURIComponent(document.URL) + '&t=' + encodeURIComponent(document.URL)); return false;"><img src="img/social-buttons/Facebook.png"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?source=&text=:%20" target="_blank" title="Tweet" onclick="window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + encodeURIComponent(document.title) + ':%20'  + encodeURIComponent(document.URL)); return false;"><img src="img/social-buttons/Twitter.png"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=" target="_blank" title="Share on Google+" onclick="window.open('https://plus.google.com/share?url=' + encodeURIComponent(document.URL)); return false;"><img src="img/social-buttons/Google+.png"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=&title=&summary=&source=" target="_blank" title="Share on LinkedIn" onclick="window.open('http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=' + encodeURIComponent(document.URL) + '&title=' +  encodeURIComponent(document.title)); return false;"><img src="img/social-buttons/LinkedIn.png"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="mailto:?subject=&body=:%20" target="_blank" title="Email" onclick="window.open('mailto:?subject=' + encodeURIComponent(document.title) + '&body=' +  encodeURIComponent(document.URL)); return false;"><img src="img/social-buttons/Email.png"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

        </div>

</div>
```

Could I create a share link that will share this particular image or any particular image in expanded view? Currently it this is using the URL which is being shared. I am unsure how to get the link to the image in the URL.

Comment: Make an individual page/url for each image and use that to share images. You can always make that page/url accessible by facebook bots and for normal users they get the parent page with that image open if you would like to.

Comment: What I've been trying, for quite a long time now, is to keep the original page loaded with the popup/enlarged version already opened when a shared link is clicked on. Making an individual page has been floating in my mind aswell, but that is a last reort.